# Python/Django filter rows with max value in a group

Tags: python, django, group-by, orm, inner-join

I saw multiple answers on this, but none of the suggested solutions helped me.

Model describes production plans for various units. Production plans are updated hourly. Each production plan is called 'layer' as they 'stack' upon each other during the day. Naturally, next 'layer' is one hour shorter than previous.

Model is as follows:

```
class PlanData(models.Model):
    plan_type = models.ForeignKey(PlanType, on_delete = models.CASCADE) # we only need type 2 here
    plan_ident = models.ForeignKey(ObjectConfig, on_delete = models.CASCADE) # decribes production unit
    plan_for_day = models.DateField() # the day of production cycle
    layer = models.IntegerField(null = True) 
      #'layer' production plan from specified hour to then of the day. 
      # layer 1 contains 24 values, layer 10 - 14 values
    hour = models.IntegerField() # hour of production
    val = models.FloatField(blank = True, null = True) # how much the unit should produce at that hour
```

What I need is to filter PlanData by getting those where layer is maximum by grouping by plan_ident and hour.

What I'm trying to do could be done in SQL like

```
select a.plan_ident, a.hour, a.layer, a.val
from dbo.asbr_plandata a
inner join (
    select max(layer) 'mlayer',plan_ident_id, hour
    from dbo.asbr_plandata
    where datediff(day,plan_for_day,getdate()) = 0
    and plan_type_id = 2 and plan_ident_id in (24)
    group by plan_ident_id, hour) b 
        on a.hour  = b.hour 
       and a.layer = b.mlayer 
       and a.hour  = b.hour 
       and a.plan_ident_id = b.plan_ident_id
where datediff(day,a.plan_for_day,getdate()) = 0
and a.plan_type_id = 2 and a.plan_ident_id in (24)
```

Yes, I can get maximum layer for each group using this:

```
pbr = PlanData.objects.filter(plan_for_day = timezone.now().date(), plan_type = 2, plan_ident__in = [10,12,13]).values('hour','plan_ident').annotate( Max('layer'))
```

But I need entire data, and if I add values somewhere in the end I get all the data, not just grouped values.

I could, of course, get a list of dicts with all the layers, and then filter it, but I my knowlege is limited I don't even know how to look it up.

How do I filter QuerySet by chosing only rows with max values?
OR How do I inner join two QuerySets?
OR How do I filter list of dicts by grouping dicts and getting max values?

Any solution works.

Comment: Maybe a custom manager with annotations is what are you looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your problem correctly, one approach, depending on your SQL dialect, could be to use a `Window` function and then filter the result. For example:

```py
from django.db.models import Window, Max, F

result = PlanData.objects.filter(
    **your_filters
).annotate(
    max_layer=Window(
        expression=Max('layer'),
        partition_by=[F('hour'), F('plan_ident')],
    )
)
```

See [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) for more on `Window` functions.

**EDIT**: Yeah forgot you can't have Window functions in the `WHERE` clause. But you will be able to filter the result more easily in Python, e.g.:

```py
filtered = filter(lambda row: row.max_layer == row.layer, result)
```

Alternatively, you could use a `Subquery` if you want to keep the result in `QuerySet` form, e.g.:

```py
from django.db.models import F, OuterRef, Subquery, IntegerField

sub_query = PlanData.objects.filter(
    **your_filters,
    hour=OuterRef('hour'),
    plan_ident=OuterRef('plan_ident'),
)

result = PlanData.objects.filter(
    **your_filters
).annotate(
    max_layer=Subquery(
        subquery.order_by('-layer').values('layer')[:1],
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
).filter(
    layer=F('max_layer')
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! It didn't work outright, because MS SQL Server only allows Window functions in Select and Order but not in WHERE section. But I'll dig into that direction.

Comment: Both solutions work for me, even though I did it less Pythony way. ```PlanData.objects.filter (
                layer = Subquery( 
                        PlanData.objects.filter(    plan_for_day = OuterRef('plan_for_day'), 
                                                    plan_ident = OuterRef('plan_ident'),
                                                    hour = OuterRef('hour')
                                                ).values('plan_for_day','plan_ident','hour').annotate(mlayer = Max('layer')).values_list('mlayer'))).order_by('hour')```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified code to the correct answer above.

```
result = PlanData.objects.filter( 
           **other_filters,
           layer = Subquery( 
               PlanData.objects.filter( 
                       plan_for_day = OuterRef('plan_for_day'), 
                       plan_ident = OuterRef('plan_ident'), 
                       hour = OuterRef('hour')                   
               ).values( 'plan_for_day',
                       'plan_ident',
                       'hour'
               ).annotate(
                    max_layer = Max('layer')
               ).values_list('max_layer')
         )
)
```